# Present a FormSheet ViewController within a UIVIewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I would like to present a UIViewController with a FormSheet presentation style within a UIVIewController through the use of Storyboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a view controller
- Make it a form sheet
- on the action seague make it modal
- change the presentation style to formsheet[image][image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the new UIViewController the main focus and have the background UIViewController not responsive until the Form Sheet is dismissed?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Ctrl+Drag from the target to the UIViewController and than select `modal`, it'll create a segue. Select the segue and on the Attributes Inspector change the Presentation to `Form Sheet`.